# Error: Undefined function or variable linspace

Tags: matlab

When I am trying to use linspace in MATLAB I am getting the above error. How do I resolve it?

I am using linspace in a very simple statement:

```
 t= linspace(0,8760,876);
```

Comment: how do you use it? Because I write exactly that and I don't get any error

Comment: Run `path` and post the result

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you try to check [internal matlab path](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~gerry/MATLAB/howTo/setMATLABpath.html)? If you get that error is because Matlab cannot find the definition of the function. Thought it is weird as it is a basic function.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a path issue. Run [`restoredefaultpath`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/restoredefaultpath.html).